# Dash dcc.upload component for large file

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I am developing a dash application. In that I have file upload feature. The file size is big enough minimum is some about 100MB to support that I have set `max_size=-1` (no file size limit).
Below is code:

```
dcc.Upload(
 id="upload_dataset",
 children=html.Div(
  [
    "Drag and Drop or ",
    html.A(
      "Select File",
      style={
              "font-weight": "bold",
            },
            title="Click to select file.",
    ),
   ]
 ),
 multiple=False,
 max_size=-1,
)
```

The uploaded files are saved on server side. This `dcc.upload` component has attribute `contents` which holds the entire data in string format using base64. While **browsing** I come to know that before sending the data to server, this `contents` is also **stored in web browser memory**.

**Problem:** for small file size storing contents in web browser memory may be fine. Since I have large file size by doing so browser may crash and app freeze.

Is there any way to by-pass this default behavior and I will like to send file in chunks or as stream?

How to achieve this in dash using dcc.upload component or any other way?

Comment: Being a common usecase while developing ML apps, I am still searching but no luck. May someone point any direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [dash-uploader](https://github.com/np-8/dash-uploader) library. It allows you to directly transfer data from the browser to the server hard drive, so you don't face any file size issues.

This library is a hobby project of the maintainer, so it might not be the most production worthy library. Though, I tested it today and it seems stable enough, I even got it to working with a Dash app that runs on an AWS Lambda.

Visit the more [extensive documentation](https://github.com/np-8/dash-uploader/blob/stable/docs/dash-uploader.md) to get started with the library.

Here is a short code example to get you started with a local version.

requirements.txt
install with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

```
dash==2.8.1
dash-uploader==0.7.0a1
packaging==21.3
```

app.py

Copy code in file app.py and run the file. It runs as-is.

```
import pprint
from pathlib import Path
import os
import uuid

import dash_uploader as du
import dash
from dash import Output, html


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

UPLOAD_FOLDER_ROOT = Path("./tmp") / "uploads"
du.configure_upload(
    app,
    str(UPLOAD_FOLDER_ROOT),
    use_upload_id=True,
)


def get_upload_component(id):
    return du.Upload(
        id=id,
        max_file_size=50,  # 50 Mb
        chunk_size=4,  # 4 MB
        filetypes=["csv", "json", "txt", "xlsx", "xls", "png"],
        upload_id=uuid.uuid1(),  # Unique session id
    )


def get_app_layout():

    return html.Div(
        [
            html.H1("Demo"),
            html.Div(
                children=[
                    get_upload_component("upload_data"),
                    html.Div(
                        id="upload_output",
                    ),
                ],
                style={  # wrapper div style
                    "textAlign": "center",
                    "width": "600px",
                    "padding": "10px",
                    "display": "inline-block",
                },
            ),
        ],
        style={
            "textAlign": "center",
        },
    )


# get_app_layout is a function
# This way we can use unique session id's as upload_id's
app.layout = get_app_layout


@du.callback(
    output=Output("upload_output", "children"),
    id="upload_data",
)
def callback_on_completion(status: du.UploadStatus):
    """Has some print statements to get you started in understanding the status
    object and how to access the file location of your uploaded file."""
    pprint.pprint(status.__dict__)
    print(f"Contents of {UPLOAD_FOLDER_ROOT}:\n{os.listdir(UPLOAD_FOLDER_ROOT)}")
    upload_id_folder = Path(status.uploaded_files[0]).parent
    print(f"Current upload_id: {upload_id_folder.name}")
    print(
        f"Contents of subfolder {upload_id_folder.name}:\n{os.listdir(upload_id_folder)}"
    )
    return html.Ul([html.Li(str(x)) for x in status.uploaded_files])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```